# Add new row if column value exist

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I have the following data.table object called `table.data`:

```
    month.option      brand som.month avg.sales distribution
1:          last SUPERBRAND 0.8860000  65.37234    0.9550000
2:      previous SUPERBRAND 0.8930000  65.31717    0.9710000
3: previous.year SUPERBRAND 0.9040000  66.16728    0.9710000
4:      all.year SUPERBRAND 0.9064906  67.50559    0.9710189
```

and I perform the following code to add a new row and get the difference with respect to the previous year :

```
table.data %>%
          select(month.option, som.month) %>%
          add_row(
            month.option = "diff",
            som.month = (filter(., month.option == "last") %>% pull()) - (filter(., month.option == "previous") %>% pull())
          ) %>%
          filter(!month.option %in% c("last", "previous")) %>%
          mutate(som.month = percent(som.month, accuracy = 0.1)) %>%
          data.table::transpose(., make.names = 'month.option') %>%
          select(diff, everything()) %>%
          set_names(c("Dif vs MA", "SOM YTD", "SOM AA"))
```

However I am having troubles with the following case:

```
    month.option      brand som.month avg.sales distribution
1:      all.year SUPERBRAND 0.9064906  67.50559    0.9710189
```

in which the previous code throws an error

> ```
> Internal error in `vec_assign()`: `value` should have been recycled to fit `x`.
> ```

I have tried several things to compensate for this case, one being the following:

```
table.data %>%
  select(month.option, som.month) %>%
  add_row(
    month.option = "diff",
    ifelse(unique(month.option) != 'all.year', som.month = (filter(., month.option == "last") %>% pull()) - (filter(., month.option == "previous") %>% pull()), "Not enough data")
  ) %>%
          filter(!month.option %in% c("last", "previous")) %>%
          mutate(som.month = percent(som.month, accuracy = 0.1)) %>%
          data.table::transpose(., make.names = 'month.option') %>%
          select(diff, everything()) %>%
          set_names(c("Dif vs MA", "SOM YTD", "SOM AA"))
```

but it still throws an error. I was wondering if anyone know how I could implement a filter that checks if I have the values "last" and "previous" in `month.option` then it performs the first code and if not it only displays the text "not enough Data"?

Comment: Please add the dataset as a reproducible object. Use `dput(head(table.data))` and share the output of that command.

Comment: internal errors should be reported to project repository as they are not meant to be visible for users

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like:

```r
# check condition
if("last" %in% table.data$month.option
   && "previous" %in% table.data$month.option){
  print("not enough data")
} else {
  # carry on with rest of calculation as per original code
  ...
}

Alternatively, you might find the `complete` function useful ([reference][1]). If you have a full table containing all your month.options and brands then this can be used to create all the missing rows and give them default values.

  [1]: https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/complete.html
```